# How do you setup a Raspbian Package Repository

Tags: update, packages, rpi-source, repository

Many of the Raspbian packages available are old and I want to update some of the software I use to the latest version. I would like to setup a local repository so my other RPi's can all pull from the same place. So how can I build packages and host a local repository? I don't want to just compile/install source code, I want to use the apt-get package manager install/uninstall things neatly.

Comment: Here's how to build packages : https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/build.en.html and how to create a local apt repository : http://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-make-my-own-local-repository Hope it helps.

Comment: This is off-topic here since it is a general Debian question (Raspbian is a Debian variant, and uses the Debian package management system). It would be on topic at [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), but I will not migrate it there directly as it would simply be a duplicate of [questions such as this one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/189075/25985). Sort of -- technically that is a question about a detail of the process, since there is already copious documentation of the process online. I suggest you read some of that and if you are confused, ask a more specific question at U&L.